# Writing binary data to unsafe pointer to primitive - Legal?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, unsafe

This works, but is it legal and portable?
Assuming that typeof(T).IsPrimitive of course.
It appears to work, but I wouldn't know where to look to see if it's allowed or not.

Yes, it's ugly, but this is mostly a question spawning from a curiosity more than anything else.

```cs
private static T Test<T>(byte[] buffer)
{
    T ret = default(T);

    unsafe
    {
        var @ref = __makeref(ret);
        var ptr = *(IntPtr*)(&@ref);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, ptr, Marshal.SizeOf<T>());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: the clr is pretty portable.

Comment: The `Marshal.Copy/SizeOf` calls should be super slow and annihilate any perf gains here. Fyi. This is fixable, question is valid.

Comment: @MacUseless I don't know what do you mean by legal, but .NET video/audio libraries use similar things.